# SSL on Cordova and prevent man in the middle attack

Tags: android, cordova, ssl, lets-encrypt, man-in-the-middle

I'm making a app in cordova, this app communicate with a API, and I would like to be this communication a secure communication.

**Some background information**

- My API has a SSL Certificate created by letsencrypt.
- In my app I'm useing the cordova-plugin-advanced-http
- To check the trafic between the app and the api I use Packet Capture [link](https://apkpure.com/nl/packet-capture/app.greyshirts.sslcapture)
- Only working for android

**Want do I want**

- Encrypted traffic
- Prevent man in the middle attack ( If this has been detected, there will be no traffic)
- If I look at Packet Capture log's I don't wanna find any information

**What did I tryed**

1. try the ssl link =

```
    cordova.plugin.http.sendRequest('https://domain.tk/API/some/endport/', function(response) {
        // prints 200
    }, function(response) {
        // prints 403
    })
```

> Data is not encrypted , I can see everything in Packet Capture

2. Made a CER file, put it in my project and pinned my connection

```
cordova.plugin.http.setServerTrustMode('pinned', function(e) {
        console.log('success!');
    }, function() {
        console.log('error :(');
    });
```

> When I starting Packet Capture TLS is not established (so no data find in Packet Capture). When I Packet Capture doesn't running traffic is working fine (GREAT)

**Problem**

The pinned methode is working "fine" the problem is if my certificat will be renewal , I always have to update my CER file in my app, and this is the problem. I'm not able to find the solution by myself.

I talked to the support of my host, and I can't see the details in there certbot (for the  --reuse-key option [link](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/help-with-renewing-ssl-certificates/110111)).

Can anyone give me tips for a encrypted traffic, that prevent man in the middle attack in a cordova app? Thanks !

Comment: did you managed to find a solution? where did you put your certificate in cordova app? I'm trying to do the same thing but pinning is not working. My environment is IIS 10 + ionic

Comment: I'm having the same problem, I wat to avoid the `man in the middle attack` but I don't want to use Certificate Pinning because I would have to lunch a new app release every time that occurs a certificate renew. If you have solved that problem, please share with us